# Error Code: 1193. Unknown system variable "block_encryption_mode"

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I want to change AES encryption mode to CBC from DEFAULT ECB, I executed the following query to change mode: My MySQL version is 5.6.10

SET block_encryption_mode = 'aes-128-cbc'

This gives following error:

ERROR CODE 1193 - Unknown system variable 'block_encryption_mode'

BUT my other machine (AWS machine) installed the same version of MySQL on that machine below statement run successfully Mysql version is 5.6.10

SET block_encryption_mode = 'aes-128-cbc'

Can anyone let me know how to solve this error?

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_block_encryption_mode *An error occurs for attempts to set block_encryption_mode to a value containing an unsupported key length or a mode that the SSL library does not support.* Also ensure that the server was compiled with SSL support included - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/source-ssl-library-configuration.html , and that SSL is not disabled - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_ssl

Comment: I am working on a Windows machine and the Mysql server version is 5.6.10.

Comment: No problems, switch to the documentation for your version (use selector in right upper corner). Or replace `/8.0/` substring with `/5.6/` in URL.